# I tried using contrapositive for this question but ended up with different answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following statement, for every $a \in \mathbb R$.
if $ a \mathbb \ge 4 $, then $ \frac{-a^2}{4} + a \le 0$

I tried using contrapositive which means assuming $ \frac{-a^2}{4} + a > 0$, then $ a \mathbb < 4 $ . Instead of ending with $ a \mathbb < 4 $, i have $ 0 < a < 4$, can someone help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem.  If you proved $0 \lt a \lt 4$, you have proved that $a \lt 4$.  You are correct that $-\frac {a^2}4+a \gt 0$ implies $0 \lt a$ as otherwise both terms on the left are negative.  You can look at $0 \lt a \lt 4$ as $0 \lt a$ and $a \lt 4$, so you proved more than was required.

Comment: But wouldnt giving a < 4  mean that all number below 4 is acceptable. considering I restrict the value 0 < a < 4 , this is not equal a < 4, hence the statement could easily  by counter proven by negative numbers?

Comment: No.  $a \lt 4$ means just what it says.  There may be other conditions on $a$ that are not shown there, as in this problem.  In another problem, there might be a way to prove $a=1$ exactly.  It is still true that $a \lt 4$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and help

Answer (score 0):

$$a\ge4 \Rightarrow a^2\ge 4a \Rightarrow 0\ge 4a -a^2 \Rightarrow 0\ge a-\frac{a^2}{4}.$$